# Which returned parameters do I need to free from GetNamedSecurityInfo API?

Tags: c++, winapi, advapi32

When I called [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and it succeeded, the MSDN states that I need to call `LocalFree` on `ppSecurityDescriptor`, but what about `ppDacl` and `ppSacl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the owner SID in the security descriptor
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the primary group SID in the returned security descriptor
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the DACL in the returned security descriptor
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the SACL in the returned security descriptor
>
> those parameters will point to the corresponding parameters in the security descriptor returned in ppSecurityDescriptor.

You only need to free `ppSecurityDescriptor` as the other pointers point to the fields within the security descriptor.